# How to alias pseudo-namespaced code using let keyword?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As a beginner in JS, I would like to understand one usage of `let` declaration, as shown below from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Description),

> You can use let definitions to alias pseudo-namespaced code in extensions. (See Security best practices in extensions.)
>
> `let Cc = Components.classes, Ci = Components.interfaces;`

What is pseudo-namespaced code?

How to alias pseudo-namespaced code using `let`keyword?

Comment: FYI, `let` has nothing to do with namespaces. It's just a different way of creating a variable.

Comment: JFTR, I've removed that paragraph from MDN now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with namespaces in Javascript, it can become quickly annoying to always specify the full namespace to access a value or method. For example:

```
let myModule = {
  mySubModule: {
    mySubSubModule: {
      myMethod: function () {}
    }
  }
};
// to use myMethod, we need to write the full namespace
myModule.mySubModule.mySubSubModule.myMethod();
```

By storing the "path" in a variable, we can avoid writing the full namespace each time we need to call myMethod:

```
let shortcut = myModule.mySubModule.mySubSubModule;
shortcut.myMethod();
```

I don't really understand why there is a paragraph specifically for Firefox extensions. As long as your browser understands the `let` keyword of the Ecmascript 6 specification,  you are free to use this technique with whatever namespace you want. It also works with the `var` keyword, although you won't benefit from features like block-scoping.

Comment: MyModule is a simple dictionary. Why do you call as module?

Comment: Can't I do this using var keyword?

Comment: There is no such things as module and namespace in Javascript. In order to achieve this, we use literal objects (or map, dictionary). Here's a link to an implementation of the Module design pattern in Javascript: [Module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

Edit: yes, you can use the `var` keyword, it's the same thing except that `let` is block-scoped and not `var`.

Comment: @Brunt: There are modules in ES6 http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-modules